# Read from a .csv the first n rows and store the column in to a list

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plot

I am facing a problem with implanting a python code that reads the first `n` `rows` from a `.csv` file and store the  values of the `columns` in a `list` . the length of the list has to be 2000, and the list will be used to create a `plot`

[image]

The `columns` in the `.csv` file are not labeled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", nrows=2000, header=None) #header = None avoids the first row to be read as column names
df_list = df.values.tolist()
```

Comment: How can i store each 'column' in designated 'list' @RJAdriaansen

Comment: You can create a list out of an individual column by using `df["column_name"].tolist()`

Comment: I used `events = df[0].tolist()`--> number of the column index and it sounds good. should that work fine? @RJAdriaansen

Comment: Yes, without column names, the columns are numbered. `df[0]` will select the first column, so `df[0].tolist()` will certainly work.

Answer (score 0):

this might help but for future reference , read pandas documentation

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(<full_path_to_file>,nrows=2000,sep=<file_seperator>)
col_list = list(df.columns)
```

Comment: This will only create a list of the column names, not of the column values.